# Trigger Creating Duplicate Records NOT in Loop

Tags: trigger

I have written code to create a Project from an Opportunity, which was working.  But for some reason it started creating duplicate records.  Does anyone see what might be wrong with this?

```
trigger ProjectCreationOpportunity on Opportunity (before update)  {
List<pse__Proj__c> projectList = new List<pse__Proj__c>();
List<pse__Budget__c> budgetList = new List<pse__Budget__c>();
List<pse__Milestone__c> milestoneList = new List<pse__Milestone__c>();


//Create list of products associated to an Opportunity.  Use this list to determine if any products are Services.  If there are Services on a Product then other items will execute. 
//In addition, the list will be used to create Milestones based on the Services
List<OpportunityLineItem> oppsWithServiceQuote = new List<OpportunityLineItem>([
   SELECT OpportunityId, Id, TotalPrice, Product2Id, Product2.Name, Product2.pse__IsServicesProduct__c, Quantity FROM OpportunityLineItem
   WHERE (Product2.pse__IsServicesProduct__c=true) AND (OpportunityId IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()) ]);

FOR(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){
    IF(Trigger.isUpdate){
    System.debug('running creart project');
    System.debug(oppsWithServiceQuote.size());
    Opportunity oldopp = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id);
        IF(opp.Create_Project__c && !oldopp.Create_Project__c && oppsWithServiceQuote.size()>0
        //Verify Record Type is CPQ and perfrom the below actions
        && opp.RecordTypeId=='012m0000000EdW8AAK'){
            projectList.add(new  pse__Proj__c(
            Name = opp.ShortOppName__c + ' ' + opp.Account_Number__c
            ,pse__Account__c = opp.AccountId
            ,pse__Is_Active__c = true
            ,pse__Is_Billable__c = true
            ,CurrencyIsoCode = opp.CurrencyIsoCode
            ,pse__End_Date__c = opp.PSA_Project_End_Date__c
            ,Internal_Notes__c = opp.Comments__c
            ,pse__Opportunity__c = opp.Id
            ,pse__Opportunity_Owner__c = opp.OwnerId
            ,pse__Practice__c = 'a20360000016A7d'
            ,Primary_Sales_Engineer__c = opp.Primary_Sales_Engineer__c
            ,Solutioning_DM__c = opp.Solutioning_DM__r.Name
            ,pse__Project_Status__c = 'Green'
            ,pse__Project_Type__c = 'RMA'
            ,Sales_Engineers__c = opp.Sales_Engineers__c
            ,SRC_Solutioning_Notes__c = 'SOLUUUUUUUUUUUUUUTION'
            ,pse__Stage__c = 'Provisional'
            ,pse__Start_Date__c = opp.CloseDate
            ,Opportunity_Record_Type__c = opp.RecordTypeId
            ));

       System.debug(projectList);

}
 }
  IF(projectList.size()>0){
            Insert projectList;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Based on the fact that you're inserting a new project record as a child of the opportunity every time the opportunity is updated, I suspect that it has always had the 'duplicate' behavior you believe is new. What does the unit test look like for this code? What are the business rules for how this is supposed to behave?

Comment: You probably have a workflow on Opportunity object that updates a field which then *refiring* the trigger again. Hence, the duplicate records. Please see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

Comment: Thank you both - but I want to ask - on the line below an IF statement checking to see if a box is checked, and to the best of my knowledge nothing is touching on this box in another trigger (unless I can find something that rolls it back and resets it) -- I created this box for this purpose.  It only happens on some Opportunities, not all.  Shouldn't it always only fire if this box goes from unchecked to checked?  Or did I set it up incorrectly?

Comment: Opportunity oldopp = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id);
        IF(opp.Create_Project__c && !oldopp.Create_Project__c && oppsWithServiceQuote.size()>0
        //Verify Record Type is CPQ and perfrom the below actions
        && opp.RecordTypeId=='012m0000000EdW8AAK')